# One R packages file for multiple Dockerfiles

Tags: r, docker, package, dockerfile, install.packages

I have built ***two*** Docker images one is my ***rstudio*** image and the other is a ***cron*** image to run my cronjobs (*R scripts*).
I am building other images (Shiny etc.) that will need the exact same R packages than the cron image and the rstudio image.
So I would like to have one single file where I can list ***all the R packages*** that will be needed for my different images.
The stucture of my folders are the following:

```
├── cron
│   ├── crontab
│   └── Dockerfile
├── rstudio
│   └── Dockerfile
├── r_packages.txt
```

As an example, for the ***Dockerfile*** of my ***rstudio*** image I tried the following:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.1

## Create directories
RUN mkdir -p /rstudio
RUN mkdir -p /rscripts

RUN cat /home/ec2-user/r_packages.txt
```

with the content of ***r_packages.txt*** as follow:

```
R -e "install.packages(c('writexl','readxl','rjson','httr','rvest','DBI','RPostgres','stringr','xlsx','knitr','kableExtra','devtools','RSelenium'))"
```

But I get the following error:

> cat: /home/ec2-user/r_packages.txt: No such file or directory

Because I assume the `r_packages.txt` should be in the same directory as my ***rstudio*** Dockerfile but I want my r_packages available for **ALL** my images, how can I achieve that?

Comment: You can also run cron from the host and have it call R inside the rstudio container.  Use something like `docker container exec -u rstudio -it mycontainer Rscript /path/to/script.R`.  This way you only need one set of packages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to run build command from the directory of your project, not where your Dockerfiles are. The reason for that is that Docker uses a concept of context, which is similar to a working directory. Docker builder cannot access files outside (above) the context directory, but it can look down into subdirectories. When you change the context from the directory with a Dockerfile, you have to specify the Dockerfile to use. For example to build the cron image you have to run:

`docker build -t cron_image_tag -f cron/Dockerfile /directory/with/r_packages.txt`

To fix the `cat: /home/ec2-user/r_packages.txt: No such file or directory` error you have to do one more thing. When you use `RUN`, you run that command inside the building container. The container won't have the `r_packages.txt` file unless you explicitly add it. Change your Dockerfile to this to fix this:

```
FROM rocker/tidyverse:3.6.1

COPY r_packages.txt /r_packages.txt
RUN cat /r_packages.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

From Dockerfile documentation

```
The COPY instruction copies new files or directories from <src> and adds them to the filesystem of the container at the path <dest>.

Multiple <src> resources may be specified but the paths of files and directories will be interpreted as relative to the source of the context of the build.
```

By default context is where the Dockerfile is. So when you build any of your Dockerfile from where it is, the file you mention is out of scope (it is in a folder below context).

To solve this build your dockerfile from the folder containing your `r_packages.txt` and tell the docker build command where your Dockerfile is using command line parameter `-f`.

`docker build -f cron/Dockerfile`

NB: You'll have to change path of files to `COPY` by prepending the folder containing your Dockerfile (here cron for your cron image) as context has changed
(`COPY cron/crontab /somewehere` I guess for you cron image)